# Отображение ещё одной строки Select2

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core

Есть проект по типу календаря загрузки авто. Но на главной странице выводится только время и название задания. [image: Главная страница]

Интересует возможность добавления в в поле рядом с "Погрузка", например, ответственного. Вот Custom JS:

```js
var routeURL = location.protocol + "//" + location.host;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#appointmentDate").kendoDateTimePicker({
        value: new Date(),
        dateInput: false
    });

    InitializeCalendar();
})

var calendar;
function InitializeCalendar() {
    try {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        if (calendarEl != null) {
            calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next,today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                },
                selectable: true,
                editable: false,
                select: function (event) {
                    onShowModal(event, null);
                },
                eventDisplay: 'block',
                events: function (fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: routeURL + '/api/Appointment/GetCalendarData?doctorId=' + $("#doctorId").val(),   /*from apicontroller route*/
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        success: function (response) {
                            var events = [];
                            if (response.status === 1) {
                                $.each(response.dataenum, function (i, data) {
                                    events.push({
                                        title: data.title,
                                        description: data.description,
                                        start: data.startDate,
                                        end: data.endDate,
                                        backgroundColor: data.isDoctorApproved ? "#28a745" : "#dc3545",
                                        borderColor: "#162466",
                                        textColor: "white",
                                        id: data.id
                                        
                                    });
                                })
                            }
                            successCallback(events);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr) {
                            $.notify("Error", "error");
                        }
                    });
                },
                eventClick: function (info) {
                    getEventDetailsByEventId(info.event);
                }
            }); 
            calendar.render();
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}

function onShowModal(obj, isEventDetail) {
    if (isEventDetail != null) {
        //editing entity
        $("#title").val(obj.title);
        $("#description").val(obj.description);
        $("#appointmentDate").val(obj.startDate);
        $("#duration").val(obj.duration);
        $("#doctorId").val(obj.doctorId);
        $("#patientId").val(obj.patientId);
        $("#id").val(obj.id);

        $("#labelPatientName").val(obj.patientName);
        $("#labelDoctorName").val(obj.doctorName);

        /*obj.isDoctorApproved ? $("#labelStatus").html('Approved') : $("#labelStatus").html('Pending');*/
        if (obj.isDoctorApproved) {
            $("#labelStatus").val('Approved');
            $("#btnConfirm").addClass('d-none');
            $("#btnSubmit").addClass('d-none');
        }
        else {
            $("#labelStatus").val('Pending');
            $("#btnConfirm").removeClass('d-none');
            $("#btnSubmit").removeClass('d-none');
        }
        $("#btnDelete").removeClass('d-none');
    }
    else {
        //adding entity
        $("#appointmentDate").val(obj.startStr + " " + new moment().format("hh:mm A"));
        $("#id").val(0);
        $("#btnDelete").addClass('d-none');
        $("#btnSubmit").removeClass('d-none');
    }
    $("#appointmentInput").modal("show");
}

function onCloseModal() {
    $("#appointmentForm")[0].reset();
    $("#id").val(0);
    $("#title").val('');
    $("#description").val('');
    $("#appointmentDate").val('');
    //$("#duration").val('');
    //$("#patientId").val('');

    $("#appointmentInput").modal("hide");
}

function onSubmitForm() {
    if (checkValidation()) {
        var requestData = {
            Id: parseInt($("#id").val()), /*from hidden tag*/
            Title: $("#title").val(), /*from _AddEditAppointment tags ids*/
            Description: $("#description").val(),
            StartDate: $("#appointmentDate").val(),
            Duration: $("#duration").val(),
            DoctorId: $("#doctorId").val(),  /*from index view of Appointment, from combobox parameters*/
            PatientId: $("#patientId").val(),
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: routeURL + '/api/Appointment/SaveCalendarData',   /*from apicontroller route*/
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.status === 1 || response.status === 2) {

                    calendar.refetchEvents();
                    $.notify(response.message, "success");
                    onCloseModal();
                    
                }
                else {
                    $.notify(response.message, "error");
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                $.notify("Error", "error");
            }
        });
    }
}

function checkValidation() {
    var isValid = true;
    if ($("#title").val() === undefined || $("#title").val() === "") {
        isValid = false;
        $("#title").addClass('error');
    }
    else {
        $("#title").removeClass('error');
    }

    if ($("#appointmentDate").val() === undefined || $("#appointmentDate").val() === "") {
        isValid = false;
        $("#appointmentDate").addClass('error');
    }
    else {
        $("#appointmentDate").removeClass('error');
    }

    return isValid;
}

function getEventDetailsByEventId(info) {
    $.ajax({
        url: routeURL + '/api/Appointment/GetCalendarDataById/' + info.id /*from method*/,   /*from apicontroller route*/
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 1 && response.dataenum !== undefined) {
                onShowModal(response.dataenum, true);
            }
            successCallback(events);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            $.notify("Error", "error");
        }
    });
}

function onDoctorChange() {
    calendar.refetchEvents();
}

function onDeleteAppointment() {
    var id = parseInt($("#id").val());
    $.ajax({
        url: routeURL + '/api/Appointment/DeleteAppointment/' + id,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 1) {
                $.notify(response.message, "success");
                calendar.refetchEvents();
                onCloseModal();
            }
            else {
                $.notify(response.message, "error");
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            $.notify("Error", "error");
        }
    });
}

function onConfirmAppointment() {
    var id = parseInt($("#id").val());
    $.ajax({
        url: routeURL + '/api/Appointment/ConfirmEvent/' + id,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 1) {
                $.notify(response.message, "success");
                calendar.refetchEvents();
                onCloseModal();
            }
            else {
                $.notify(response.message, "error");
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            $.notify("Error", "error");
        }
    });
}
```

Вот контроллер:

```cs
namespace AppointmentScheduling.Controllers.Api
{
    [Route("api/Appointment")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ApiController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAppointmentService _appointmentService;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly string loginUserId;
        private readonly string role;

        public ApiController(IAppointmentService appointmentService, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _appointmentService = appointmentService;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            loginUserId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            role = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Role);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("SaveCalendarData")]
        public IActionResult SaveCalendarData(AppointmentVM data)
        {
            CommonResponse<int> commonResponse = new CommonResponse<int>();
            try
            {
                commonResponse.status = _appointmentService.AdUpdate(data).Result;
                if(commonResponse.status == 1)
                {
                    commonResponse.message = Helper.appointmentUpdated;
                }
                if (commonResponse.status == 2)
                {
                    commonResponse.message = Helper.appointmentAdded;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                commonResponse.message = e.Message;
                commonResponse.status = Helper.failure_code;
            }

            return Ok(commonResponse);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetCalendarData")]
        public IActionResult GetCalendarData(string doctorId)
        {
            CommonResponse<List<AppointmentVM>> commonResponse = new CommonResponse<List<AppointmentVM>>();
            try
            {
                if(role == Helper.Patient)
                {
                    commonResponse.dataenum = _appointmentService.PatientsEventsById(loginUserId);
                    commonResponse.status = Helper.success_code;
                }
                else if(role == Helper.Doctor)
                {
                    commonResponse.dataenum = _appointmentService.DoctorsEventsById(loginUserId);
                    commonResponse.status = Helper.success_code;
                }
                else if (role == Helper.Admin)
                {
                    commonResponse.dataenum = _appointmentService.DoctorsEventsById(doctorId);
                    commonResponse.status = Helper.success_code;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                commonResponse.message = ex.Message;
                commonResponse.status = Helper.failure_code;
            }

            return Ok(commonResponse);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetCalendarDataById/{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetCalendarDataById(int id)
        {
            CommonResponse<AppointmentVM> commonResponse = new CommonResponse<AppointmentVM>();
            try
            {                
                commonResponse.dataenum = _appointmentService.GetById(id);
                commonResponse.status = Helper.success_code;                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                commonResponse.message = ex.Message;
                commonResponse.status = Helper.failure_code;
            }

            return Ok(commonResponse);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("DeleteAppointment/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAppointment(int id)
        {
            CommonResponse<int> commonResponse = new CommonResponse<int>();
            try
            {
                commonResponse.status = await _appointmentService.Delete(id);
                commonResponse.message = commonResponse.status == 1 ? Helper.appointmentDeleted : Helper.somethingWentWrong;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                commonResponse.message = ex.Message;
                commonResponse.status = Helper.failure_code;
            }

            return Ok(commonResponse);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("ConfirmEvent/{id}")]
        public IActionResult ConfirmEvent(int id)
        {
            CommonResponse<int> commonResponse = new CommonResponse<int>();
            try
            {
                var result = _appointmentService.ConfirmEvent(id).Result;
                if(result > 0)
                {
                    commonResponse.status = Helper.success_code;
                    commonResponse.message = Helper.meetingConfirm;
                }
                else
                {
                    commonResponse.status = Helper.failure_code;
                    commonResponse.message = Helper.meetingConfirmError;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                commonResponse.message = ex.Message;
                commonResponse.status = Helper.failure_code;
            }

            return Ok(commonResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

Заранее, спасибо!)

Comment: Укажите конкретнее, что именно вызывает трудности.